# Explicit wait is not working for Firefox (52.4.0 (64-bit))

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Explicit wait is not working for Firefox (52.4.0 (64-bit))below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://XXXX/XXXXX/XX/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Viewer']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Viewer']")).click();
}
```

I have to use Explicit wait here in any case as elements doesn't get loaded in fixed time. I have searched lot in google but didn't find any code working for me.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code attempt it seems you are waiting for the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) through [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) and then trying to invoke [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) method. In your code you have used the clause [presenceOfElementLocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749269/java-wrapper-method-for-waiting-for-element-to-be-available-for-apache-cordova-w/49752577#49752577) with [ExpectedConditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712), which as per the [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#expected-conditions) doesn't confirms if the *WebElement* is ***Displayed*** and ***Enabled*** as well.

A better solution will be to modify the clause for [*ExpectedConditions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749269/java-wrapper-method-for-waiting-for-element-to-be-available-for-apache-cordova-w/49752577#49752577) where instead of presenceOfElementLocated we have to use [*elementToBeClickable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699674/java-selenium-expectedcopnditions-presence-passes-but-visibility-fails/65702948#65702948) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Viewer']")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [presenceOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-). As per documentation:

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
>   page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

You have to be sure that you are waiting on the element the correct expected condition.

Answer (score 1):

as per @DebanjanB , i just it is not an good idea to use `presenceOfElementLocated` instead it is always better to use  `elementToBeClickable` so correct code should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://XXXX/XXXXX/XX/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Viewer']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Viewer']")).click();
}
```