# Java Wrapper method for waiting for element to be available for Apache Cordova Webview driven App

Tags: cordova, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriverwait

For Multiple Webview based Mobile App (iOS app built using Cordova, PhoneGap, XCode), I have created below method to check if element is present. Kindly suggest if below snippet makes sense? as traditional wrapper functions based on traditional Explicit waits are not working reliably.

```
    public boolean waitForElemToBeAvailable(final By by, final int timeout, int retries) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(appiumDriver, timeout);
    boolean success = false;
    final long waitSlice = timeout/retries;

    if(retries>0){
        List<WebElement> elements = appiumDriver.findElements(by);
        if(elements.size()>0){
            success = true;
            return success;
        }else {
            appiumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(waitSlice, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            retries--;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code block you have shared I don't see any value addition to check *if element is present* through `implicitlyWait`. The implementation looks as a pure overhead. Instead if you look into the *Java Docs* of [ExpectedCondition](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html) Interface from the **org.openqa.selenium.support.ui** package which models a condition that might be expected to evaluate to something that is not null nor false also contains the [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) Class that can be called in a loop by the [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) Class and the *methods* provides more granular approach to confirm if a particular condition have achieved or not. This gives us much more flexibility in choosing the desired behavior of a *WebElement*. Some of the widely used methods are :

- Presence of an element :

  ```
  presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)
  ```
- Visibility of an element :

  ```
  visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
  ```
- Interactibility of an element :

  ```
  elementToBeClickable(By locator)
  ```

**Note** : As per the [documentation](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any recommendation/snippet for Appium Cordova driven App, (where we have more than 3-4 webviews stacked-up.)?

Comment: @user2451016 I am afraid, I am not accustomed with _Appium Cordova driven App_ but _ExpectedConditions_ are quite proven and works flawless.

Comment: @user2451016 Upvote the Answer if it was useful to you for the future readers

Comment: Unfortunately for Multiple WebView driven Cordova app, we experience that ExpectedConditions are not working reliably, perhaps as there're multiple WebViews stacked -up alongwith default Native_view.

Comment: @user2451016 Can you raise a new question with a _usecase_ where _ExpectedConditions are not working reliably_?