# Wait until element is clickable does not timeout correctly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait, pageloadtimeout

I'm having some problem handling timeouts as it doesn't seem to be working in every situation. I have defined the timeout as follows:

```
 wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Now, when I want to wait until an element is present on the page, I use this piece of code :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

It works in most of the situation (wait for the element and timeout after 60 seconds) but lately we've been having trouble with some of the pages that get stuck loading (there's a message waiting for ... at the bottom left of the page). When this happens, I realize that this piece of code doesn't work properly. It doesn't timeout after 60 seconds but after 10 minutes.

**Edit**: Actually, trying to investigate my problem a little more, I realized it really comes from another line of code that also contains the wait:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
```

Basically, I click on a link that redirects to another page, wait for a button to be present, wait for the button to be clickable, and click on the button. So it detects the button is present but then it waits for it to be clickable and doesn't time out after 60 seconds.

So when I define my driver, I added the following line:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In the console, I see the following line:
    Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000

But how do I catch this exception? I tried to surround my wait with a try/catch but it doesn't work.

```
try {
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.info("TEST");
throw new TimeoutException("element " + locator.toString() + " not found on the page");
}
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*?

Comment: Well, since the page is still loading, the element is not present on the page. So I expect a timeout after 60 seconds, but it doesn't happen. Like I said, the timeout is after 10 minutes rather than 60 seconds. From what I can see, this problem only occurs when the page doesn't load

Comment: During a pageload Selenium will wait until a pageready state.  There's not much you can do if the page doesn't load except try to figure out why it's taking so long.  The pageload timeout is global and it's happening between your driver calls... so can't be caught there... you can only catch it on a .get()...

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- Waiting until an element is present on the page ideally won't help much if your usecase is either to get any of the attributes, e.g. *classname*, *innerHTML*, etc of an element or to invoke `click()` on an element.
- Instead depending on your *usecase* you need to use either [visibilityOfElementLocated()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) or [elementToBeClickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-).
- You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

  - [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)
  - [Java Wrapper method for waiting for element to be available for Apache Cordova Webview driven App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749269/java-wrapper-method-for-waiting-for-element-to-be-available-for-apache-cordova-w/49752577#49752577)
  - [Selenium: Check for the presence of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712)
- The reason for the line of code `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator))` doesn't times out after **60 seconds** but after **10 minutes** may be due to the reason that, along with [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) you have also configured [Implicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) and as per the [documentation](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) mixing up [Implicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588966/python-selenium-difference-between-driver-implicitly-wait-and-time-sleep/53589205#53589205) and [Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518467/how-to-properly-configure-implicit-explicit-waits-and-pageloadtimeout-through/50524225#50524225) can cause [**unpredictable wait times**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706693/how-to-combine-implicit-and-explicit-timeouts-in-selenium/52707885#52707885)
- To configure [pageLoadTimeout](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) you can use the following code block:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try{
      driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/the-taj-mahal-palace-tower.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYATG4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=338ad58d8e83c71e6aa78c67a2996616;dest_id=-2092174;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;hip_dst=1;hpos=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=ccd41231d2f37b82d695970f081412152a59586aX1;srpvid=c71751e539ea01ce;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl");
    }catch(WebDriverException e){
      System.out.println("WebDriverException occured");
      }
    driver.quit();
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    [1563377008.449][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 1.999
    [1563377008.450][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
    [1563377008.461][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.012
    [1563377010.466][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 1.998
    [1563377010.467][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
    [1563377010.476][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.010
    WebDriverException occured
    ```
- You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881)