# Bug with selenium java & chromedriver 77 on element.getAttribute('id')?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait, google-chrome-headless

Since the release of Google Chrome 77, I updated our CI process so headless automated testing is done with:

- selenium-java 3.141.59 (maven)
- ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/chromedriver_linux64.zip)
- Google Chrome 77.0.3865.90 (77.0.3865.90-1, retrieved via http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main)

A simple code who worked perfectly doesn't work anymore, because **element.getAttribute('id') returns null** instead of the string value of id attribute of the HTML element (which has been found using By.id() !)

I tried such config on Windows and Linux (docker) and the result is the same: getAttribute('id') returns null instead of the HTML element id

Simplified code to reproduce the problem:

```java
String myId = "myInputTypeDateId" ;
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
String eltId = element.getAttribute("id");
// With chrome 76 & chromedriver 76: returns "myInputTypeDateId"
// With chrome 77 & chromedriver 77: returns null
```

Additional info:

- the element related to the problem is an `<input type = "date">`
- I am using Aura components framework (Salesforce lightning)

Did someone detected a similar issue with Chrome/Chromedriver 77 ?

Any advice about some workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a compatibility bug between chromedriver and Salesforce

It is solved in chromedriver 78 , but the only way to make it work with Chrome 77 seems to use chromedriver 76 with chrome 77

We are several users to ask for a chromedriver 77 patch, but it is not provided yet

More details here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3103#c6

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *id* attribute as you are trying to invoke `getAttribute()` from an `<input>` element, instead of using `presenceOfElementLocated()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* either for the `visibility_of_element_located()` or `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `visibilityOfElementLocated()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myInputTypeDateId"))).getAttribute("id"));
  ```
- Using `elementToBeClickable()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("myInputTypeDateId"))).getAttribute("id"));
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Java Wrapper method for waiting for element to be available for Apache Cordova Webview driven App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749269/java-wrapper-method-for-waiting-for-element-to-be-available-for-apache-cordova-w/49752577#49752577)

Comment: The HTML element is existing in the DOM if it is returned by presenceOfElementLocated. Why should it be mandatory visible or clickable to be able to get it's id attribute ?

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy `presenceOfElementLocated` doesn't guarantees the element will be _visible_ or _interactable_ within the _HTML_. So in your usecase waiting for `visibilityOfElementLocated` would be optimal. However being an `<input>` element it would turn _clickable_ within delta additional span of time.

Comment: Sometimes i have to force the scroll to make an element visible & clickable, that's why i need to use the "present" check.
But as described in my reply, it's a chromedriver bug ... thanks for your answer !

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy `elementToBeClickable` would scroll the element before clicking by default. However I have provided a reference discussion. Let me know if it helps.