# How to extract the value when there is no value tag using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I want to get value of input tag and compare with sum of 2 numbers. But there is no value tag, or I can not see result number. I tried to get but I got null. The picture and Input tag is like under.

```
<input _ngcontent-lbg-c92="" matinput="" type="number" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c35-2 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine" style="text-align: center;" id="mat-input-2" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" disabled="">
```

Element snapshot:

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

To print the *value* i.e. ***1626*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.mat-input-element[id^='mat-input'][type='number'][matinput]")).getAttribute("value"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'mat-input-element') and starts-with(@id, 'mat-input')][@type='number' and @matinput]")).getAttribute("value"));
  ```

---

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [presenceOfElementLocated()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752577/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[id*='Empty'][value='emptyAssembly']"))).getAttribute("value"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@value='emptyAssembly' and contains(@id, 'Empty')]"))).getAttribute("value"));
  ```

Comment: So can I use value tag even there is no value tag in input tag ?

Comment: @BatuhanBAKAR Ofcoarse you can.