# how to triple-click on python to select a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent

Someone please tell me a way to triple-click on selenium python. I tried this and other things but it did not work.

```
for x in range(3)
   actions.click()
```

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer that solves your issue to help others with similar questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will triple click on the question you asked on this page. Hope it helps. The tricky part is pyautogui does not care about where the browser window is.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pyautogui


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253535/how-to-triple-click-on-python-to-select-a-paragraph')
driver.maximize_window()

test_paragraph = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(), 'Someone please tell me a way to triple-click ')]")))

# import time
# time.sleep(3)
panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')
abs_x = test_paragraph.location['x']
y = test_paragraph.location['y']
abs_y = y + panel_height
print("Absolute x : " + str(abs_x))
print("Absolute y : " + str(abs_y))

pyautogui.moveTo(abs_x + 10, abs_y)
pyautogui.click(clicks=3)
```

Comment: Checkout [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) doesn't provide any way to perform a triple click. However a feasable approach would be to simulate the desired *mouse events* using `execute_script()` method as follows:

```
def  js_triple_click(element, deltaY = 60, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0):
    driver.execute_script("""
      "var target = arguments[0];                                 " +
      "var offsetX = arguments[1];                                " +
      "var offsetY = arguments[2];                                " + 
      "var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();                 " +
      "var cx = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width / 2));        " +        
      "var cy = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height / 2));        " +
      "                                                           " +
      "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
      "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
      "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
      "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
      "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
      "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
      "emit('click',     {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, detail: 3});  " +
      "                                                           " +
      "function emit(name, init) {                                " +
    "target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(name, init));        " +
      "}                                                          " ;
    """)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "p"))) # replace the locator as per your usecase
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
js_triple_click(element)
print("Tripple click performed")
```

Console Output:

```
Tripple click performed
```

Comment: I like this strategy but the `element` passed to the function `js_triple_click` is never passed as an argument to the `execute_script`.

Comment: This almost worked for me. It showed the bottom left url link bar to me but it did not click. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Help please...?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I would say that you are missing the perform action:</s>

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for i in range(3):
    actions.click()
    actions.perform()
    print('click')
```

<s>Does it work now?</s>

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Try to locate two elements and then use *drag_and_drop* with those elements as source and end of the command. The code below seems to work and selects the paragraph.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
# first element and last element in the paragraph
start = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/div[1]')
end = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/div[4]')

actions.drag_and_drop(start, end).perform()
```

I used Wikipedia as a test and I took the xpath of two lines of text. The script selected the paragraph in between. So it should be okay. Let me know

Comment: It does a double-click instead.

Comment: @MoisesPark can you try with a while loop instead? check my answer

Comment: @MoisesPark maybe you can try to set higher range. I tried on my side and I've got triple or multiple clicks.

Comment: Did it select a paragraph?

Comment: By doing a double-click i meant it selects a word only, not a paragraph

Comment: @MoisesPark Maybe try to import `Keys` and send Keys with CONTROL, 'a'. Something like `element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')`

Comment: @MoisesPark found it! Check this out, I updated my answer. Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try hard coding it.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

def triple_click(element_x):
    actions.click(element_x).click(element_x).click(element_x).perform()

triple_click(your_element)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Then you can try this:

```
times = 3
while(times >0):
            ActionChains(driver).click().perform()
            times -= 1;
```

Comment: It does a double-click instead too. I think it has to do with selenium ActionChains.

Answer (score 0):

If timing isn't an issue you could get away with:

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.double_click()
actions.click()
actions.perform()
```

Otherwise you can build your own w3c actions directly:

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.click()
actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.click()
actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.click()
# don't forget to add a slight pause -- see actions.double_click()
for _ in range(4):
    actions.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()
actions.perform()
```