# Selenium, build XPath in java, to click on the button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need please your help to build XPath, click on the button :

[image]

HTML is :

```
<div class="offer col-md gtm-data gtm-impression slick-slide" data-gtm-id="5608" data-gtm-title="230 גיגה Rolling Package" data-gtm-price="33.00" data-gtm-category="חבילות" data-gtm-list="homepage" data-gtm-position="4" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 370px;" xpath="1">
    <div class="upper">
        <div class="title"><spam class="threshold">230</spam><spam class="units">GB</spam></div>
        <div class="subtitle"><p>Rolling Package</p>
</div>
        <!--<div class="comment"><span>test</span></div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="price-area">
        <div class="title"><spam class="price-number"><span class="number">33</span></spam> </div>
        <div class="subtitle">
            <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="link">
            <a href="en/userGuide/step1?packageidReg=5608&amp;packageidChange=5609&amp;process=CustomerGuide" class="button red full gtm-click" title="Join Now" tabindex="-1" style="">Join Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When I try to click on the button,
by XPath :

```
//div[contains(@data-gtm-id, '5608')] //a[@class='button red full gtm-click']
```

I got this error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="userGuide/step1?packageidReg=5608&amp;packageidChange=5609&amp;process=CustomerGuide" class="button red full gtm-click" title="..." tabindex="0">להצטרפות</a> is not clickable at point (951, 858). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

When I try :

```
(//a[contains(@class,'button red')])[2]
```

I can click on the button,
But I want the code to be more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The *`data-gtm-id`* attribute is a [Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer) attribute and the value of *data-gtm-id* attribute i.e. *5608* is dynamically generated. Everytime you access the application it would get changed. So you won't be able to locate the element using the attribute *data-gtm-id*

---

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element with text as ***Join Now*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *linkText*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Join Now")).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.button.red.full.gtm-click[title='Join Now']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='button red full gtm-click' and text()='Join Now']")).click();
  ```

---

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *linkText*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Google"))).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.button.red.full.gtm-click[title='Join Now']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='button red full gtm-click' and text()='Join Now']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
The tag "data-gtm-id", in our system is to define the packages that the customer can purchase,
It's not dynamic,
There are several in the system,
For each package - have its number,
So it does define each package as unique,
Can you please give me an example since I can enable this button, depending on the "data-gtm-id" TAG?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your element is right but it is clicking before it is loaded, so please add wait condition.

```
By joinNowBtn = By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Join Now')]");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(joinNowBtn));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(joinNowBtn));
driver.findElement(joinNowBtn).click();
```