# Clicking on a check box using selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, checkbox

I am trying to click on a check box. Below is the HTML Code

```
<div class="mb-1 p-3 termsCheck">
            <input class="form-check-input float-end" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required=""> <label class="form-check-label float-end" for="flexCheckDefault"><span>
                    Agree to Terms &amp; Conditions </span> / <span> أوافق على الشروط والأحكام
            </span> </label>
        </div>
```

I am using the below code to click on it.

```
check = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#flexCheckDefault')
check.click()
```

I am getting this error

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (477, 1222)
```

full error:

```
     driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flexCheckDefault']").click()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 81, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (292, 1317)
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x556910005919 <unknown
```

Can some please help me with this.

when I am using the below code I am getting this error::

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flexCheckDefault']"))).click()
```

Error

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flexCheckDefault']"))).click()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 81, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (292, 467)
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x563f45805919 <unknown>
```

Comment: If your locator is correct, then can you use java script click ?WebDriverRunner.driver().executeJavaScript("arguments[0].click();", check);

Comment: any idea how to code it in python? I dont use JS

Answer (score 0):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the checkbox beside the label ***Agree to Terms & Conditions*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css-selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='flexCheckDefault']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flexCheckDefault']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on a ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS-SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='flexCheckDefault']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='flexCheckDefault']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried and I am getting this error:
aise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (292, 1317)

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status. If you still see the error, update the question with the complete error stacktrace even beyond `Element is not clickable at point (477, 1222)`

Comment: I updated the question. when i an using what youve suggested, i am getting a similar error

Comment: More of the stacktrace i.e. `#0 0x563f45805919` lines would have been helpful. You seem to be using _chrome=91.0.4472.101_, can you upgrade to `chrome=96.0` and `chromedriver=96.0` and get me the status please?

Comment: @raptorzee Can you replace your line where you are clicking with this: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", check)")

Comment: this is how it works. thank a lot

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[6]/input')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

@QualityMatters can you please post it as an answer so i can make it the answer

Comment: @raptorzee done. If you will run it with jenkin (windows slave) which opens with a different screen resolution or in any machine having different resolution, then also this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

`ElementClickInterceptedException` is usually comes when the element is not in viewport. In such cases, JavaScript executor works perfectly in selenium scripts. Below code should work:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```