# Click button in using VBA Chrome selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Good night
I want to click the upload image button using chrome selenium
I've tried to code, but it doesn't work

```
Public Sub CallChrome1()
    Dim ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim strFolder As String
    
     Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strFolder = wsh.regread("HKCU\Volatile Environment\LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Google\Chrome\User Data"
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    ch.AddArgument ("user-data-dir=" & strFolder)
    ch.AddArgument ("profile-directory=Default")
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://sellercenter/apps/product/publish"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    
    ch.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://sellercenter/apps/mediacenter"
    ch.SwitchToNextWindow
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    ch.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='next-btn next-medium next-btn-primary' and text()='Upload Image']").Click
       MsgBox "Press OK to Close"
End Sub
```

this is the html code

```html
<button type="button" class="next-btn next-medium next-btn-primary" role="button">Upload Image</button>
```

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate any advice on how to click this button using the Selenium in Excel VBA, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*`By.CLASS_NAME`* accepts a single classname. So you can't pass multiple classnames with in *`FindElementByClass()`*.

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element <kbd>Upload Image</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
  ch.FindElementByCss("a.next-btn.next-medium.next-btn-primary").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))     
  ch.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='next-btn next-medium next-btn-primary' and text()='Upload Image']").Click
  ```

Comment: Thank you 

I've tried all the code above, but it doesn't work

Comment: @anggun Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjaB
code not working

See my code above which I have updated

Comment: @anggun Where are you stuck exactly? What error do you see?

Comment: element not found
[link](https://ibb.co/VW4VNDf)

Answer (score 0):

First thing in selenium when you are writing selectors, always check their occurrence. If you want to click on particular element then selector should show 1 matching count.
Now here you have use class value which looks like it have more than one matching node as well as you can use class value this way in selenium when there is more than one class(more words separated by space in class value).

So here I would recommend to use below xpath and before using it in your code, verify it if it is showing one matching node-

```
//button[text()='Upload Image']
```

Comment: SelectorsHub - XPath Plugin
not working

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you add 10sec wait before clicking on upload image button and see if it works.

Comment: no error
but there is no click

Comment: How many match it is showing on that page for this xpath- //button[text()='Upload Image']
Please make sure it is finding 1 matching node. If possible, please your page link, I will help you with the solution.

Comment: Hello @
SelectorsHub - XPath Plugin


After I tried on Selenium without Profile,

Code successful,


But, why if run on selenium chrome Profile,
the code is not working , is there something wrong ?

Comment: If I use Chrome Default profile then the code doesn't work ,If I use Profile 2 Code works fine ,Where did it go wrong?