# Website Auto Login button VBA code is not working

Tags: excel, vba, scada

I am using the below code to enter the server page. I am inspecting the html code and fill the data accordingly. Filling Username and passwords are success, but login button is not working. The code posted below. Instead of calling IExplorer, I am using activX name it as WebCamVBA for my SCADA.

```
Private Sub Display_AnimationStart()

Dim HTMLDocs As HTMLDocument
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "http://192.168.1.1/"

WebCamVBA.Silent = True
WebCamVBA.Navigate (MyURL)
WebCamVBA.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until WebCamVBA.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = WebCamVBA.Document
HTMLDoc.all.username.Value = "admin1"
HTMLDoc.all.password.Value = "*****"

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByName(“input”)
If MyHTML_Element.Type = “login” Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

Login button html code provided below

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I see it correctly, clicking the submit button triggers a JavaScript. I assume that the environment you are using can't do that, so nothing happens. Have a look at Seleniumbasic. You should not use IE, as you probably already know. Read the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps

Comment: No it is working.  Finally I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Option Explicit

Sub WbClkMe()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://apiweb.biomerieux.com/login"
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signupEmail") ' This is based on on your website
HTMLInput.Value = "" 'Put the value of Usernamae
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signupPassword") 'This is based on on your website
HTMLInput.Value = "" 'Put the value of Password
Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signupSubmit") 'This is based on on your website
HTMLButton.Click

End Sub
```

Or, maybe this?

```
Sub WebsiteLogin()

Const url As String = "https://login.my_site_here.jsp"
Const userName As String = "Here Your LogIn Name"
Const passWord As String = "Here Your Password"

Dim ie As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeInputUserName As Object
Dim nodeInputPassWord As Object

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set htmlDoc = ie.document
  
  'Set the log in name
  Set nodeInputUserName = htmlDoc.getElementById("USERID")
  nodeInputUserName.Value = userName
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, nodeInputUserName, "onkeypress")
  
  'Set the password
  Set nodeInputPassWord = htmlDoc.getElementById("PASSWORD")
  nodeInputPassWord.Value = passWord
  Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, nodeInputPassWord, "onkeypress")
  
  'Click submit button
  htmlDoc.querySelector("a[role='button']").Click
  
End Sub

' This is the procedure to trigger events:

Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)
  Dim theEvent As Object
  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: clicking the submit button triggers a JavaScript. So the above part is not useful.

Comment: Right, right...IE is pretty old...I think it's been retired by now. Maybe this...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234705/click-button-in-using-vba-chrome-selenium

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Even it is java script, it is working with the below code

```
For Each Element In MyHTML_Element.Links
If InStr(MyHTML_Element.innerText, "Login") Then
Call MyHTML_Element.Click
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
End If
Next
```