# How to bypass cookiebot.com uc.js by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to find a way to click on the cookie agreement button created by the javascript code that is provided by `cookiebot.com` such as the following example in a HTML code,

```
<script id="Cookiebot" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" data-cbid="8123486-d5f-ec" data-blockingmode="auto" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have searched the net, but there is no example showing how to do that using Selenium Python.

Comment: So when I go to cookiebot.com you just want to hit the allow all right?

Answer (score 1):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element <kbd>Allow all</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.cookiebot.com/en/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.cookiebot.com/en/")   
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```