# How to click checkbox inside a div-table in selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, checkbox, css-selectors

I have been trying various methods to check a check box inside a

```
<div>
<table id="Table1" class="Foresttable" style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" 
border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25%;" align="left">
<input id="ChkDeclaration" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ChkDeclaration"> 
<label for="ChkDeclaration">Yes I agree</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

but its failing.

Trial#1

```
Dim Actions1 As Selenium.Actions
Actions1.MoveToElement(d.FindElementById("ChkDeclaration")).Click.Perform
```

It says Object or block variable not set

Trial#2

```
dim ChkDeclaration0 as selenium.webelement
set ChkDeclaration0=driver.FindElementByID("ChkDeclaration")
ChkDeclaration0.Click
```

says not clickable at this point, some times **WORKS**

Trial#3

I tried `sendkeys(Keys.Return)` also does not work

Pls give some clue how to do this.

Comment: The element might not be loaded immediately so you could try doing a `While` loop checking if the element exist before you click it e.g. `Do While driver.FindElementByID("ChkDeclaration") Is Nothing: DoEvents: Loop` and once it escape the loop, it means the element should be loaded and you can then click it.

Comment: @Raymond Wu I tried it, It escapes loop but still shows same error. Seems like issue is not related to control not being ready.

Answer (score 0):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  d.FindElementByCss("label[for='ChkDeclaration']").click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  d.FindElementByXPath("//label[@for='ChkDeclaration']").click
  ```

Comment: I tried both above it gives error, when i debug it passes thru successfully.Even i put a delay loop but no difference. Thanks for editing.