# Can't click on a treeview with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm basically new to automation testing, been using JAVA+SELENIUM, Eclipse.

Been trying to open the "Europe" tree with the geckodriver.exe Webdriver. Been searching for solutions, but to no avail.

This is the page, that needs to be tested.
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Common/NavigationOverview/Angular/Light/

My code for opening the tree.

```
public class Test_suite {
    
    @Test
    public void testAssertFunctions() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\selenium-3.141.59\\draiveri\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Common/NavigationOverview/Angular/Light/");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        WebElement fruits = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/demo-app/div/div[1]/dx-tree-view/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/div[2]"));
        fruits.click();
        }
    }
```

It seems I can't locate the element, have tried multiple `findElement.by` options, but to no help. Only solution that sort of worked was using Selenium IDE, which did the click to expand the tree, and it shows `xpath=//li[4]/div[2]`, but after copying that path to eclipse, still does not find the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```java
public class Test_suite {
    @Test
    public void testAssertFunctions() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\selenium- 
    3.141.59\\draiveri\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Common/NavigationOverview/Angular/Light/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='demoFrame']")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='demoFrame']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Europe']"))).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this solutions but now I get the timeoutException, I even changed the wait to 30, but it just can't find that element. Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //span[text()='Europe']

Comment: I'm sorry. That element is inside an iframe. So you have to switch to that iframe first in order to access this element. See my updated answer.

Comment: The updated version  worked, but as the upper answer, if the Europe button is clicked, it needs a double click to open the tree. Is there no way to trigger the triangle expansion button, then it would only take one click.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- With [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ***v3.x*** onward as using [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) is mandatory, so instead of:

  ```
  webdriver.firefox.driver
  ```

  we need to use:

  ```
  webdriver.gecko.driver
  ```
- Instead of an *absolute xpath* you need to use a *relative xpath*.
- The desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is also within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- Ideally to [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on any ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  @Test
  public void testAssertFunctions() throws InterruptedException {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\selenium-3.141.59\\draiveri\\geckodriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.navigate().to("https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Common/NavigationOverview/Angular/Light/");
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame' and @name='demo-frame']")));
      WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Europe']")));
      new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).doubleClick(element).build().perform();
  }
  ```

Comment: what do I put after @class= ?

Comment: @PēterisSpura Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: the test passed, though I did not see the click needed to open the tree, it does not open still.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the click is on the EUROPE button, not on the tree expansion button. I can try to do the double click, then it should open.

Comment: @PēterisSpura Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Thank You. The last update did the double click so it worked!