# clicking the download button is not working properly in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, cucumber-java

I did not face any error as no element found however my test case is passed in console but when i checked in download folder it shows some temp file instead of actual image file. It will be very useful if someone solve this issue.

```
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/elements");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            // Here normal 'findElement' is not working, hence used the javascript executor
            
            WebElement leftmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@id='item-7']//span)[1]"));
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", leftmenu);  //clicking the left menu 
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@download='sampleFile.jpeg']")).click();  // download button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finishing the test run and closing the browser immediately after clicking the download button.
Try adding a simple sleep after clicking it.
Also, you should not use hardcoded pauses like this

```java
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Explicit wait should be used instead.
Also please try to wait until the element is visible, as I wrote here. I think this will let you clicking it with regular driver `.click()` method.
Try this:

```java
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/elements");

driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, globalDelay);
            
// Here normal 'findElement' is not working, hence used the javascript executor
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//li[@id='item-7']//span)[1]"))).click();            
//WebElement leftmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@id='item-7']//span)[1]"));
//JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", leftmenu);  //clicking the left menu 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@download='sampleFile.jpeg']"))).click();            

Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element <kbd>Download</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *linkText*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#downloadButton[download^='sampleFile']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='downloadButton' and starts-with(@download, 'sampleFile')]")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally, to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *linkText*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Download"))).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a#downloadButton[download^='sampleFile']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@id='downloadButton' and starts-with(@download, 'sampleFile')]"))).click();
  ```

> PS: Once you click on <kbd>Download</kbd> don't close the web browser immediately and wait for sometime for the download process to be completed.