# Python selenium I can't acess to a linked page on a page with iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I want to go from this page to this https://resultats.ffbb.com/organisation/b5e6211d5970.html to this page https://resultats.ffbb.com/championnat/b5e6211f621a.html?r=200000002810394&d=200000002911791&p=2 by clicking on 'Régional féminin U15'.
I have tried many solutions but the best I had, is not working systematically.
Please coul you help me?

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://resultats.ffbb.com/organisation/b5e6211d5970.html")

driver.switch_to.frame("idIframeChampionnat")
#sign_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/pre/span[93]'))).click();

button = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(u"minin U15")
button.click()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the link with text as *Régional féminin U15* as the elements are within an [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://resultats.ffbb.com/organisation/b5e6211d5970.html")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#idIframeChampionnat")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Régional féminin U15"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://resultats.ffbb.com/organisation/b5e6211d5970.html")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='idIframeChampionnat']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Régional féminin U15"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: resultats]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
driver.switch_to.frame("idIframeChampionnat")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'minin U15')]")
button.click()
```

or

```
driver.switch_to.frame("idIframeChampionnat")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'minin U15')]"))).click()
```

This is my code example in groovy (sorry, haven't python env), pretty similar to yours, and it works perfectly 20 times in a loop even without timeouts.

```
    @Test(invocationCount = 20)
    void test() {
        driver.get('https://resultats.ffbb.com/organisation/b5e6211d5970.html')
        driver.switchTo().frame(
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='idIframeChampionnat']"))
        )
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'minin U15')]")).click()
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
        assert driver.getCurrentUrl() ==
                'https://resultats.ffbb.com/championnat/b5e6211f621a.html?r=200000002810394&d=200000002911791&p=2'
    }
```

So, I have no ideas. Maybe just add `driver.switch_to.default_content()` after click?

Comment: Thank for your proposition, Ihave tried both solutions and with both solutions I stay on the same starting page.

Comment: Rectification it has worked (the 2nd solution) but only once on 10 trys.

Comment: @Elmanu20, could you please share your error message/stack trace? You might enrich your question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any trace. This codes does not produce  any visible effect most of the time, and sometimes it works..

Comment: Added some updates to the answer.

Comment: Ok thank a lot. I have just seen that's my webbrowser is not ok because it works perfectly on an other one.

Comment: I'm using chrome v96 + selenium 4.0 with default capabilities.

Comment: I am using chrome v96 and it works, but until now I was on Firefox where there are random behavior. I didn't try to reinstall my original web browser yet. Thank for your help!