# Selenium Python: Unable to scroll and click on Load more stories button

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, webdriverwait, js-scrollintoview

I am new to Selenium and would appreciate advice. I am trying to click on the load more stories button on NPR's website (https://www.npr.org/sections/news/). My code seems good, but when I run it more stories are never loaded. I don't get an error at the same time the code just doesn't behave as expected.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/myname/projects/myproject/geckodriver')
# implicit wait for 5 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.npr.org/sections/news/')

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[2]/section/div[7]/button')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage [**npr**](https://www.npr.org/sections/news/) have a *infinitescrollwrap*. As a demonstration to [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) thrice on <kbd>Load more stories</kbd> you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.npr.org/sections/news/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.global-modal__dismiss"))).click()
  for i in range(3):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.options__load-more"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.options__load-more"))).click()
    print("Load more stories clicked")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Load more stories clicked
  Load more stories clicked
  Load more stories clicked
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much for this response. 

When I try the above code, I still get an error -- this time on the 4th line (the line with driver.execute_script()`


TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:181:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:393:5
element.find/</<@chrome://marionette/content/element.js:306:16

Comment: @generic What error does it throws? I've added the required imports.

Comment: I think I had the wrong imports and adding your imports fixed the problem. This was my error:

Comment: TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:181:5 NoSuchElementError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:393:5 element.find/</<@chrome://marionette/content/element.js:306:16

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what happened but I am getting that same error (above) again.

Comment: I am using the exact code, no edits.

Comment: @generic Can you check with Chrome browser once, code is tested with Chrome.

Comment: @generic You shouldn't see a **`NoSuchElementError`** by any means with my code as I don't have `find_element*`

Comment: Let me restart everything. I may have done something dumb.

Comment: I restarted VSCode, changed to chromedriver (instead of Firefox's Gecko driver), and I get the following error on that same line (driver.execute_script ...)

Comment: TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56333b40aee3 <unknown>
#1 0x56333aed8608 <unknown>
#2 0x56333af0eaa1 <unknown>
#3 0x56333af0ec61 <unknown>
#4 0x56333af41714 <unknown>
#5 0x56333af2c29d <unknown>
#6 0x56333af3f3bc <unknown>
#7 0x56333af2c163 <unknown>
#8 0x56333af01bfc <unknown>
#9 0x56333af02c05 <unknown>
#10 0x56333b43cbaa <unknown>
#11 0x56333b452651 <unknown>
#12 0x56333b43db05 <unknown>
#13 0x56333b453a68 <unknown>
#14 0x56333b43205f <unknown>
#15 0x56333b46e818 <unknown>
#16 0x56333b46e998 <unknown>
#17 0x56333b489eed <unknown>
#18 0x7f50f99f9590 <unknown>

Comment: I am using the exact code as above, and have not run anything else.

Comment: @generic The current error stacktrace is possibly of a driver-browser mismatch, can you check the versions of both?

Comment: My chrome version is: 96.0.4664.110 (for Ubuntu) 
My chrome driver is the same

Comment: @generic There is no `ChromeDriver v96.0.4664.110` but [ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/)

Comment: So then I probably need to find Chrome version v96.0.4664.45. That's what I get for not reading the last two digits right. I'll be right back after looking for that version

Comment: @generic Go ahead and keep me updated.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding Chrome version 96.0.4664.45. It's not listed here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php, and the websites that say they offer 96.0.4664.45 seem really shady and also say it's for Android. This is where I got my Chrome driver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads . Maybe I need a different chrome driver? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @generic For smaller and shorter doubts feel free to visit [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room to get help and at the same time help others.

Comment: Wow a whole Selenium room -- thanks for this -- I will post my driver issue there as well, and also do some more experimentation.