# How to click on a button in python using selenium with aria-label

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to find and click a *close* button on an iframe.

```html
<modal-container class="modal fade show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;" aria-modal="true"><div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-xl"><div class="modal-content"><div _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" class="modal-header card-header modal-header-news-expanded"><h4 _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" align="center" class="modal-title col-11 text-center">Article Title PDF </h4><button _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" aria-label="Close" class="close close_white_color" type="button"><span _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div><br _ngcontent-gtk-c9=""><div _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" class="container-fluid"><!----><div _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" class="row"><!----><div _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted"><!----><iframe _ngcontent-gtk-c9="" id="pdf_iframe_outside_modal" src="link.com" class="ng-star-inserted" cd_frame_id_="337af673cf64fd1888fcd2afe645984c"></iframe><!----></div></div><!----></div></div></div></modal-container>
```

I have tried the following methods:

Try1:

```
close = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label=Close']").click()
```

Try2:

```
close = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='close close_white_color']").click()
```

Try3:

```
close = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,\"close close_white_color\")]").click()
```

Which gives following error

Error1:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@aria-label='Close']"}
```

Error2:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='close close_white_color']"}
```

Error3:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class,"close close_white_color")]"}
```

I am able to interact with the iframe but unable to locate this button. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Can you share a link to that page or at least all that page HTML and more of your code?

Comment: @Prophet Have added extended page HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here:

- The element isn't within the [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) doesn't returns anything.

---

### Solution

The desired element is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp), to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.close.close_white_color[aria-label='Close'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  //button[@class='close close_white_color' and @aria-label='Close']/span
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB. You are correct, I have an iframe within a Modal Dialog Box. I want to download the pdf which is within the iframe and then click 'close' (as in the question) located in the Modal Dialog Box. Once i switch to iframe and download the pdf, i am unable to run the your solution, it gives me an error _StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document_.