# Selenium VBA - Click on a Download Button

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm new with selenium vba and I'm trying to click on a download button, this button is inside a kind of pdf iFrame:

Here is some HTML:

```
<cr-icon-button id="download" iron-icon="cr:file-download" aria-label="Fazer o download" title="Fazer o download" aria-haspopup="false" aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0"></cr-icon-button>
```

and here is what I tryed so far:

```
 1 : ChromoLink.FindElement(By.linktext("Fazer o Download")).Click
 2 : ChromoLink.FindElementByLinkText("Fazer o Download").Click
 3 :ChromoLink.FindElementsByCss("input")(1).Click
 4: ChromoLink.FindElementByClass("toolbarButton download hiddenMediumView").Click
 5: ChromoLink.FindElementById("download").Click
 6: ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/pdf-viewer//viewer-toolbar//div/div[3]/viewer-download-controls//cr-icon-button//div/iron-icon").Click
 7: ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/pdf-viewer//viewer-toolbar//div/div[3]/viewer-download-controls//cr-icon-button//div/iron-icon").ClickAndHold
 8: ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/pdf-viewer//viewer-toolbar//div/div[3]/viewer-download-controls//cr-icon-button//div/iron-icon").Click
 9: ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""download""]").ClickAndHold
10: ChromoLink.FindElementByCss("[title='baixar']").Click
```

None of those worked

Error:
[image]

I know that print it's not a good idea, but I'm not able to just copy the whole html:

[image]

Comment: For better help, Can you share the site link on which you are performing these actions?

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh it's a internal website, so I'm not able to share the link. But, I added a picture.

Answer (score 1):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element first you have to switch to the [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *FindElementsByCss*:

  ```
  ChromoLink.SwitchToFrame "iFrameReport"
  ChromoLink.FindElementByCss("cr-icon-button#download[title='Fazer o download'][aria-label='Fazer o download']").Click
  ```
- *FindElementByXPath* relative to *Claims*:

  ```
  ChromoLink.SwitchToFrame "iFrameReport"
  ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("//cr-icon-button[@id='download' and @title='Fazer o download'][@aria-label='Fazer o download']").Click
  ```

Comment: It's not working yet, I realize that the element is inside a iFrame and the name of the iFrame is id="iFrameReport" so, I SwitchToFrame but response and give me a arror.

Comment: @Pedro Added the code for frame switching. Let me know the status.

Comment: After frame switching by FindElementsByCss or FindElementByXPath it reports that "element was not found".

Comment: @Pedro Induce some wait between the two lines

Comment: I was already using some wait between switching the frame and find the element, perhaps that it's not reaching the element.