# Web objects locators for Edge browser?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hey I'm new to web automation , I just startes to write my scenarios and link them to related steps using java framework:

I tried different methods for this button :

[image]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath/className)
```

and I always got this exception in my code:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

exemple used: WebElement filter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id ='sidebarCollapse']"));
    filter.click();
```

Can anyone help me (see the attached image ) ?

Answer (score 0):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#sidebarCollapse[title='Filtres de recherche']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='sidebarCollapse' and @title='Filtres de recherche']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to *`click()`* on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span#sidebarCollapse[title='Filtres de recherche']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@id='sidebarCollapse' and @title='Filtres de recherche']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Hello DebanjanB, I still get the error :  no such element: Unable to locate element: , i tried both locators css & xpath :(