# How to automate elements without a class id in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to automate the pressing of the following button in selenium, but I'm used to referring to elements using their ID. This button has no ID:

```
<button type="button" class="button-error en-button" ng-transclude="" 
en-tap="AssignDateTime();showModal('utilities/assignment 
editior/delete',{item:item}, assignmentslist.refresh)" style="touch- 
action: manipulation; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; - 
webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">

<en-icon icon="trash" class="ng-scope">
</en-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Use css selector .button-error.en-button ?

Answer (score 0):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button-error.en-button[en-tap^='AssignDateTime'][en-tap*='assignmentslist']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button-error en-button' and starts-with(@en-tap, 'AssignDateTime')][contains(@en-tap, 'assignmentslist')]").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button-error.en-button[en-tap^='AssignDateTime'][en-tap*='assignmentslist']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button-error en-button' and starts-with(@en-tap, 'AssignDateTime')][contains(@en-tap, 'assignmentslist')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use just class:

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-error').click()` or `driver.find_element_by_class_name('en-button').click()`

or

if you find multiple elements with same class name then use xpath

`//button[@class='button-error en-button']` or `(//button[@class='button-error en-button'])[1]`