# For loop selenium click

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, while-loop

I want to click 5 times on an element in selenium how can i do this using for loop or while loop in python
i have tried using for loop in python below is the code

```
nextButton = driver.find_element_by_id("com.sustlabs.ohmassistant:id/btn_next")

for nextButton in range(5):
    nextButton.click()
```

Comment: Do you see any error? Update the question with the relevant HTML of the _Next_ button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) 5 times on an element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use a _`for()_` loop and inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511)as follows:

```
for i in range(5):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "com.sustlabs.ohmassistant:id/btn_next"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I am assuming the next button is going to a new page so this combined with a try except would be the best option.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan You are right. But using try, in-case the click is missed, `range(5)` may not click 5 times. Catch 22 situation :)

Comment: If we had a lot pages in the range, could we get blocked? Does this method do anything to prevent the server thinking it could be a denial of service attack? It this where an explicit wait would come in?