# Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on button using partial css path:

Full xpath:

```
// /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/mat-dialog-container/mobileweb-outbound-pick-picking-dialog/mobileweb-outbound-pick-confirmation/div/div/div/mobileweb-client-area/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/mobileweb-action-button[1]/div/button
    // //*[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]
```

I tried this Java Selenium web driver code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    WebElement until = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("//mat-dialog-container/mobileweb-outbound-pick-picking-dialog/mobileweb-outbound-pick-confirmation//*[@id=\"source-lp.select-lp.button\"]")));
```

But I get error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.cssSelector: //mat-dialog-container/mobileweb-outbound-pick-picking-dialog/mobileweb-outbound-pick-confirmation//*[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:231)
    at org.mobile.outbound.pick.picking.clusterpicking.ClusterPickingPickTest.buildEmptyClusterFromShipmentId(ClusterPickingPickTest.java:361)
    at org.mobile.outbound.pick.picking.clusterpicking.ClusterPickingPickTest.Mobile_Web_Cluster_Picking_Pick_66732(ClusterPickingPickTest.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

...as the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have used is a qualified [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) however within your code trials you considered it as a [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors).

Further, as per your code trials assuming the element to be a <kbd>button</kbd> element with value of `id` attribute as *`source-lp.select-lp.button`*, you can use a relative locator and you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  //button[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  button[id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]
  ```

---

Ideally, to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on any ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]"))).click();
  ```

---

### Update

For the element within *parent1*:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//parent1//button[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]"))).click();
```

For the element within *parent2*:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//parent2//button[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the provided solution. However I found one issue: I have multiple components which hold inner components with same id. Example: `//parent1/componet//button[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]"` and `//parent2/componet2//button[@id="source-lp.select-lp.button"]"` What are the available options here?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you've specified an XPath but used `By.cssSelector()`.

Your second line should be

```
WebElement until = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//mat-dialog-container/mobileweb-outbound-pick-picking-dialog/mobileweb-outbound-pick-confirmation//*[@id=\"source-lp.select-lp.button\"]")));
```

Also note that the XPath you put in your question is not the same one you are using in the code you posted.

XPaths that start at //html, have that many levels, and/or use indices are very brittle (they break easily with even small changes to the page). You should spend some time learning how to handcraft locators to avoid this issue.

That giant XPath you have can be reduced down to just `By.id("source-lp.select-lp.button")` instead of an XPath. Always look for ids, names, and other attributes that are unique on the element before turning to a large XPath.

Comment: I got error `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable`

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't interact with any elements so I can't really comment on why you're getting that error. If you need help, you should create a new question that contains the relevant code and HTML as well as the error message, etc.

Comment: `ElementNotInteractableException` means that the element you've located and are trying to interact with is probably hidden or somehow otherwise not interactable. I would suggest you check your locator and make sure that you are finding the element you are intending to find.