# Unable to scroll webpage using .scrollTo() and .scrollIntoView() in selenium (python) any other way to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scroll down a webpage "https://www.novitecgroup.com/en/brands/ferrari/roma/" using selenium for python. So far I have tried using following but none seem to work. Please suggest me a better way make it work.

My End goal is to scroll down the webpage and get the browser to automatically click one of those car parts under Suspension and also Aerodynamics.

{NOTE: x in following code is a place holder for a specific part I am trying to scroll to and then  click}

using scroll To function

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x)
```

Using arguments.scroll into view function

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", x)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x)
```

Thank you for you help in advance

Answer (score 1):

To scroll down the webpage and get the browser to automatically [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on *Suspension* or *Aerodynamics* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) which automatically scrolls the element into the view and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Clicking on *Suspension* using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.novitecgroup.com/en/brands/ferrari/roma/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='cookie-confirm__submit']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Suspension']"))).click()
  ```
- Clicking on *Suspension* using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.novitecgroup.com/en/brands/ferrari/roma/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#cookie-confirm__submit"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='aerodynamic']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```