# How to search in a webpage using selenium despite using correct search id

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to search a web page using selenium. Below is the HTML code snippet of search page.

```
<div class="cmp-globalsite-search ac_box">
     <input id="searchString" type="text" class="form-control searchString 
          ac_input" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" required="" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="hidden" id="searchTargetUrl" value="/en/search">
     <a class="searchHead btn" href="#">
     <span class="nav-icon gcom-icon-search"></span>
     </a>
</div>
```

The above one is taken from `https://www.gartner.com`.

I am using below python code to use the search page.

```
url = 'https://www.gartner.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path to chrome web driver')
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("SearchString")
elem.send_keys("Risk Management Solution")
elem.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
```

Strange thing is I am getting the below error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
selector","selector":"[id="SearchString"]"}
(Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

I have tried below as well:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//input[@id="searchTargetUrl"]/input[@value = "Risk Management Solution""")
```

Getting similar error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath 
expression //input[@id="searchTargetUrl"]/input[@value = "Risk Management Solution because 
of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 
'//input[@id="searchTargetUrl"]/input[@value = "Risk Management Solution' is not a valid 
XPath expression.
(Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

I am novice to selenium and therefore asking for any clue.

**Update**

I have copied the `full xpath` of the search page from the above site.

```
//*[@id="gartnerinternalpage-9ac4556e05"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input
```

So I had replaced the above xpath string in the python code and added `//input[@value={0}]`

Still no luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Search* field is not visible by default, to send a *character sequence* to the search field you need to [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the *search* icon first inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.gartner.com/en")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.nav-icon.gcom-icon-search"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#searchString"))).send_keys("Risk Management Solution" + Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.gartner.com/en")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='nav-icon gcom-icon-search']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='searchString']"))).send_keys("Risk Management Solution" + Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: gartner_com]