# Selenium Python click href element no attributes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, attributes

Hello I need to click on a `href` link but it doesn't have any class, id, text or anything at all.

```
<div>
<a href="/ad/repost/id/2109701">
    <span>Réafficher</span>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh">
    </i>
</a>
```

I've tried the following and multiple other things.

```
Link = driver.find_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="body"]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a/span'))
```

But it throws an error.

I also have the same issue with an input button :

```
<div class="modal-pm-left">
    <input type="button" class="btn-orange modal-close" value="Fermer">
</div>
```

help >_<

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the `href` element with the following locators:

```
"//a[contains(@href,'/ad/repost/id/2109701')]"
```

or

```
"//a[./span[text()='Réafficher']]"
```

The `input` element can be located with

```
"//input[@value='Fermer']"
```

I can't be 100% sure about uniqueness of the locators above without seeing the actual web page HTML

Answer (score 0):

The *`href`* attribute is part of the parent A tag, which also have a descendant SPAN which contains the text ***Réafficher***. So invoking click on the SPAN would also result as similar as clicking the A tag with the *`href`* attribute.

---

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element with text as ***Réafficher*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='2109701'] span").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]//span[text()='Réafficher']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on a ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='2109701'] span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href]//span[text()='Réafficher']"))).click()
  ```

---

Similarly, to click on the *`<input>`* button you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn-orange.modal-close[value='Fermer']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn-orange modal-close' and @value='Fermer']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```