# How to click the cross on the banner at site www.di.se with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

**Description**: I work on scraping the stocks on site [www.di.se](http://www.di.se). The site content is blocked by a banner. I have always clicked the cross by the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ElementName")).click();
```

Exact name on the element is now:  "svg.icon.icon--feather-close.icon-feather".

But recenly the have done something so this code to click away banner by clicking the cross is not working.

**Question**
How do I click the cross on the banner to make it disappear?

Answer (score 0):

The *Close* icon seems to be had been removed from the current deployment.

As an alternative you can [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on <kbd>Godkänn alla</kbd> element within the banner element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#didomi-notice-agree-button"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='didomi-notice-agree-button']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I really wonder if we have the same view? I can see a cross in the top right corner of the banner but not the button "godkänn och stäng". The banner is internal ad about a digital subscription of their paper.

Comment: @torbjörnsödheim Not a native German, the text is _Godkänn alla_ with _id_ as `didomi-notice-agree-button` which I've incorporated within the answer.

Comment: I tested to open DI link with Edge browser and I get a different ad than with Chrome I use with Selenium. Probably you see a different ad because we use different browsers!

Comment: Finally I resolved the issue but it was a strange fault! The banner did not popup when program ran headless so I just comment the click and then all was ok! The strange thing is when not ran headless a banner like the one you describe (using Chrome browser with Selenium). When webbrowsing I use Chrome as browser but the banner wasn't like the other I described before with a cross. I don't understand why site differs and why headless and not headless are different!?