# Web Scraping: How to click a specific href link in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wanted to automate a web page using webdriver(Python) wherein the script will click on the href link directly in order to navigate to other page. Couple of details in the specific tag:

```
<span class = "xyz", ui-sref ="abc", href= "/letters/letters_number/"> 
"hdf"
<i class = 'icons'>letters</i>
</span>
```

Comment: Search the stack, it has 100 questions on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, Gaj. But what I have mentioned in the description above, the tag details, I couldn't find a great match. Hence, would need someone's help.

Comment: click the link like you would normally see how the URL looks and append that href to the base URL and then call your webdriver driver.get() to get that page

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on a the element with the *`href`* attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[href=/letters/letters_number/] i.icons"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@href='/letters/letters_number/']//i[@class='icons']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you.It's working now