# Selenium: Trying to login but the same page is reloaded after click

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login a page.

I entered the e-mail & password inputs by *`element.sendKeys()`* without any error.

After that I need to click the 'loginButton' button. But the button is defined as non keyboard-focusable.

When I run the automation, the button is clicked. But the automation is not continue with the next page (main page); just reloads the same page with empty inputs.

I tried several ways to click the button and also tried to enter by using 'ENTER' key;

```
// **1.**
 loginButton.click();

// **2.**
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// **3.**
 Actions act = new Actions(dDriver);
 act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton"))).click().build().perform();

// **4.**
 JavascriptExecutor executor;
```

All of them seems that I can click the button but after that as I mentioned, the page is reloaded, not continue with the next page.

What else can I try?

Comment: Please give a link to the site / URL you are trying to automate.

Comment: What about shoot out js `document.submit()`?

Comment: Here is the site: https://www.n11.com/giris-yap @TalAngel

Comment: Are you entering a correct Username and correct Password via the code?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure; because when I am entering manually, it is correct. By the way, if I enter wrong, the warning/error message should be displayed; like, 'The E-mail Address or password is wrong.'. Also, I tried with the wrong inputs in automation, when I tried it, the page is reloaded again as same way. @TalAngel

Answer (score 0):

A problem I can think about is that you are typing the information too fast and hit the login button right away.

Try to wait before clicking the Login button 0.3 seconds:

```
Thread.Sleep(300);
```

Or even a full second:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Tell me if this solves your issue.

Also, the site might be disabled for automation code so add these to your ChromeOptions:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"}); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Or

```
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

Comment: Yes I tried it but not worked. Also, I tried the use Implicit Wait, but also not worked.

Comment: So, the site has protection against Automation password input. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Yes, I tried your updated solutions as well but not worked. Maybe as you can said, the site can blocks the automated login process.

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element <kbd>Giriş Yap</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.green_flat#loginButton"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='green_flat' and @id='loginButton'][text()='Giriş Yap']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I tried these now, but still same.