# Python/Selenium: Click on button element without ID attribute

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, click

Hi I want to click on this button but I don't know how to find it, it has no explicit NAME or ID, also, what is the code to simulate a mouse click?

This is the HTML:

```
<button class="aOOlW  bIiDR  " tabindex="0">Accept All</button>
```

---

This is the part of the code:

```
auth = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'aOOlW  bIiDR  ')
auth.send_mouse(Keys.LEFT)
```

As you can see `send_mouse(Keys.LEFT)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method as *`send_mouse(Keys.LEFT)`*

---

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element with text as ***Accept All*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[tabindex='0']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All']").click()
  ```