# How can I extract the text from a webelement using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

Here I have tried to access leetcode question title, which are available on the given link. However I seem to not be able to access the text in the specified web element. The error I get says:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I also get a warning:

```
service = Service(executable_path=gecko, log_path='geckodriver.log')
DeprecationWarning: log_path has been deprecated, please use log_output
```

Please help me fix these, since I cannot find any solution which does not return the same error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

# URL of the page with questions
url = 'https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?page=1&topicSlugs=array'
gecko= 'path'
i = 3
# XPath expression for the elements containing the text
xpath_expression = f"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a"
firefox_path="path"

options = Options()
service = Service(executable_path=gecko, log_path='geckodriver.log')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_expression)
element_text = element.get_attribute('text')
print(element_text)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You are looking for the (single) element with text as ***63. Unique Paths II***. So you instead of [`find_elements()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) you need to use [*`find_element()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072347/7429447).

---

### Solution

However to extract the **visible** text ***63. Unique Paths II*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and using the index `[0]` you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?page=1&topicSlugs=array')
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/problems/unique-paths-ii/'][class^='h-5']")))
  print(elements[0].text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?page=1&topicSlugs=array')
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@class, 'h-5') and @href='/problems/unique-paths-ii/']")))
  print(elements[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `find_elements` method that returns a collection instead of `find_element` that returns single element.
Collection doesn't have attribute `text`.

To return text from single element, you should use

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_expression).text
```

If you want to print all text from elements within collection, you can use loop:

```py
for element in paragraph_elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Also I suggest to use more concrete xPath expression to locate your element / elements.

Something like CSS selector `[role=row] .truncate a`

Comment: Hello, I think I do need a more concrete xPath expression to locate the element(s)
But I am not sure how to do so, could you help out there
The problem arising here is that when I try to use elements, it is returning an empty list, which I presume means that it doesn't really get to the element I want it to get to

I did infact get this 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a

Comment: Can you make a screen / show, what element or elements are you trying to get?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/snTXDnS
I wish to extract "1. Two Sum" as you can see on the left side
I have copied its XPath and URL and putting it into this code
It still is not running, I do not know how

Comment: @amspsingh04 this element can be found by
`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.truncate [href*=two-sum]')`

Comment: thank you so much, got it done with this and undetected-selenium 's answer

Answer (score 1):

The web element returned is a list, so this should work in your case

```
element_text = element[0].text
```

but ideally, a list implies several elements so would make sense to iterate over

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_expression)

for element in elements:
    element_text = element.text
    print("Element text:", element_text)
```