# Clicking a button image using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click that button, I've tried several ways and I couldn't.

**bottom id = edita_cliente**

HTML:

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="color: #ace;">
                <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-title" style="text-align: left; font-size: 16px;margin: 5px;">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px">
                            <i style="padding-left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" id="novo_cliente" class="tooltipped fas fa-plus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Novo cliente"></i>
                            <i style="padding-left: 15px; cursor: pointer;" id="edita_cliente" class="tooltipped far fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-valor="203739" data-original-title="Editar cliente"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on a element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i#edita_cliente[data-original-title='Editar cliente']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@id='edita_cliente' and @data-original-title='Editar cliente']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It wasn't, I just tried