# How to click the button via Selenium with 'onclick' info only?

Tags: python, html, selenium, button

The only thing html has with the button is:

```
<button onclick="exportTableToCSV('hahaha.csv')">export as csv</button>
```

No class or id or name or type.
Tried with xpath and link text, neither works.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[onclick=\"exportTableToCSV('hahaha.csv')\"]").click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text("export as csv").click()
```

Both return to error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[onclick="exportTableToCSV('hahaha.csv')"]"}

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"export as csv"}

Help appreciated!!!

Comment: If it's not there it's either in an iframe or hasn't loaded yet. I would use this css: `button[onclick*=hahaha]`

Answer (score 0):

You can locate this element with XPath or CSS Selector.
The locator you tried has some syntax error.
Please try this XPath:

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"exportTableToCSV('hahaha.csv')\"]").click()
```

Or this CSS Selector

```py
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[onclick=\"exportTableToCSV('hahaha.csv')\"]").click()
```

In case `exportTableToCSV` is an unique value you can also use this XPath

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@onclick,'exportTableToCSV')]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried all 3 but not working, all returns " Message: no such element: Unable to locate element".

Comment: exportTableToCSV is a self defined function in html, would this make a difference?

Comment: Maybe you just missing a wait / delay? Or the element is inside an iframe?

Comment: Looks like here it is just a string, this should not make problems

Answer (score 0):

The text ***export as csv*** is the text of the `<button>` element but not of an `<a>` tag. Hence you can't use *`find_element_by_link_text()`* to locate the desired element.

---

### Solution

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on a element with text as ***export as csv*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick^='exportTableToCSV']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(@onclick, 'exportTableToCSV') and text()='export as csv']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: The driver wait works! Thank you!