# Clicking on a link using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, partiallinktext

Please need your support to click on a link in the following:

[image]

I tried the below code but doesn't work:

```
web.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="HUI_i_0"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a').click()
```

It gives me error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="HUI_i_0"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use link text to locate element:

```
web.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Subscriber Administration').click()
```

If link is dynamic try to add [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried it but failed too

Comment: @AhmedTantawy check if link [is in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python).

Comment: Excuse me but how can I check it?

Comment: @AhmedTantawy check if link is descendant of `iframe` node

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "tbody > tr > td.treeNode > a"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.signin-btn.sbLoginBtn > span.btf-text"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Subscriber Administration')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)