# How to identify this element using selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried to select the element below using xpath, id, class, nothing is working. This is the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ui-id-26"]"}
```

HTML code of the element:

```
<a title="" href="#8eef8ef4-7cfc-4cb6-69cf-1cabf9625d74" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-26">Data</a>
```

Snapshot of the element:

[image: the element I want to select and eventually click]

I am using python.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
chromedriver = 'C:/Users/misha/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://login.cmegroup.com/sso/accountstatus/showAuth.action")
driver.maximize_window()
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginBtn")

name = driver.find_element(By.ID, "user")
name.send_keys("MyEmail")
pwd = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pwd")
pwd.send_keys("MyPassword")
login.click()

time.sleep(15)

driver.get('https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/cme-fx-market-profile-tool.html#analyze-more')


data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ui-id-26"]')

data.click()
```

Comment: import time and try to add a time.sleep(5) between data and driver.get(url)

Comment: If possible add HTML snippet for the page. Also make sure that element you want to interact is not within the `iframe`

Comment: The element `Id` could be dynamic or If not then element could be inside an `iframe`. You need to post the relevant html for better solutions.

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: /html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a is the full xpath @undetected Selenium if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as ***Data*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Data").click()
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.ui-tabs-anchor[id^='ui-id'][title]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ui-tabs-anchor' and starts-with(@id, 'ui-id')][text()='Data']").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Data"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.ui-tabs-anchor[id^='ui-id'][title]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ui-tabs-anchor' and starts-with(@id, 'ui-id')][text()='Data']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: when I use By it says 

element=driver.find_element(By.ID,"myname")
NameError: name 'By' is not defined. Did you mean: 'py'?

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`