# How to click on dynamic hyperlink which has dynamic text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to click on the dynamic URL using selenium python from a web page. I have the following HTML where ***123456*** is dynamic text linked to dynamic URL.  I am not able to use `driver.find_element_by_link_text()` as text also dynamic. Can someone please help me with this?

```html
<td class="resultsColumn"><a href="xyz.jsp?serviceID=123456=">123456</a></td>
```

**Note: Both URL and Text also dynamic**

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the **dynamic URL** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.resultsColumn > a[href*='serviceID']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='resultsColumn']/a[contains(@href, 'serviceID')]").click()
  ```

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.resultsColumn > a[href*='serviceID']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='resultsColumn']/a[contains(@href, 'serviceID')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```