# how to locate a button for selenium

Tags: selenium, button

```
<button id="export-button" aria-label="export transactions" color="primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-component-id="Button" class="Buttonstyle__StyledButton-sc-1vu4swu-3 cHnaSs"><div class="Buttonstyle__StyledFlexContainer-sc-1vu4swu-0 bEnvol"><div class="Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc-1vu4swu-1 bAsplb"><svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="Iconstyle__StyledIcon-sc-82cwdi-0 doMWlN"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 18.75V11.5a.75.75 0 111.5 0v8a.75.75 0 01-.75.75H5.25a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75v-8a.75.75 0 111.5 0v7.25h12zM12.767 6.322l-.02 10.292a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0l.02-10.315L8.38 9.185a.75.75 0 01-1.06-1.06l4.155-4.155a.75.75 0 011.06 0l4.231 4.23a.75.75 0 01-1.06 1.062l-2.94-2.94z"></path></svg></div>Export</div></button>
```

[image]

I like to locate the imaged button to use selenium. I have tried using ID,xpath, Link_TEXT, css_selector as below, but none of them worked.

```
export_btn=browser.find_element(By.ID,'export-button')
export_btn=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="export-button"]/div')
export_btn=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[normalize-space()="Export"]')
export_btn=browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Export')
export_btn=browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#export-button')
export_btn=browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#export-button > div')
```

would you please help me to locate the button?

Thank you in advance,
hoo

**UPDATE -20Feb22-**

Thank you undetected Selenium, cruisepandey !!

I still cannot locate the button. It is my bad. I should have provided more information as possible. This is an online banking site so that URL link won't work.

The button consists of 2 divided parts. one for upper arrow shape and the other is the Export word itself.
The element that I had provided is `Export` button as a whole. there are more details of the three elements

**Export button as a whole**

element

```
<button id="export-button" aria-label="export transactions" color="primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-component-id="Button" class="Buttonstyle__StyledButton-sc-1vu4swu-3 gzjAAB"><div class="Buttonstyle__StyledFlexContainer-sc-1vu4swu-0 bEnvol"><div class="Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc-1vu4swu-1 bAsplb"><svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="Iconstyle__StyledIcon-sc-82cwdi-0 doMWlN"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 18.75V11.5a.75.75 0 111.5 0v8a.75.75 0 01-.75.75H5.25a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75v-8a.75.75 0 111.5 0v7.25h12zM12.767 6.322l-.02 10.292a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0l.02-10.315L8.38 9.185a.75.75 0 01-1.06-1.06l4.155-4.155a.75.75 0 011.06 0l4.231 4.23a.75.75 0 01-1.06 1.062l-2.94-2.94z"></path></svg></div>Export</div></button>
```

Selector

```
#export-button
```

XPATH

```
//*[@id="export-button"]
```

Full XPATH

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/miniapp-transactions//div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/button
```

**upper arrow**

element

```
<svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="Iconstyle__StyledIcon-sc-82cwdi-0 doMWlN"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 18.75V11.5a.75.75 0 111.5 0v8a.75.75 0 01-.75.75H5.25a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75v-8a.75.75 0 111.5 0v7.25h12zM12.767 6.322l-.02 10.292a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0l.02-10.315L8.38 9.185a.75.75 0 01-1.06-1.06l4.155-4.155a.75.75 0 011.06 0l4.231 4.23a.75.75 0 01-1.06 1.062l-2.94-2.94z"></path></svg>
```

Selector

```
#export-button > div > div > svg
```

XPATH

```
//*[@id="export-button"]/div/div/svg
```

Full XPATH

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/miniapp-transactions//div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/button/div/div/svg
```

**Export word itself**

element

```
<div class="Buttonstyle__StyledFlexContainer-sc-1vu4swu-0 bEnvol"><div class="Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc-1vu4swu-1 bAsplb"><svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="Iconstyle__StyledIcon-sc-82cwdi-0 doMWlN"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 18.75V11.5a.75.75 0 111.5 0v8a.75.75 0 01-.75.75H5.25a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75v-8a.75.75 0 111.5 0v7.25h12zM12.767 6.322l-.02 10.292a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0l.02-10.315L8.38 9.185a.75.75 0 01-1.06-1.06l4.155-4.155a.75.75 0 011.06 0l4.231 4.23a.75.75 0 01-1.06 1.062l-2.94-2.94z"></path></svg></div>Export</div>
```

Selector

```
#export-button > div
```

XPATH

```
//*[@id="export-button"]/div
```

Full XPATH

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/miniapp-transactions//div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/button/div
```

I believe if I can click one of the three, Export will be executed.
Thank you for your time for helping me !!

hoo

PS
I attach the button image with a new button, if I succesfully can click the export button, the new one will show.

[image]

**Update -21Feb22**

I have noticed the export button appears only when they have some transactions to show. It prevents to locate the button? I attached the image of the part of the codes.

[image]

Comment: In order to give you a locator we need to see that page - please provide a link to that page if possible or at least the entire XML / HTML code of that page. We have nothing to do with picture you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Export"
```

is a text node, Selenium usage **xpath v1.0** so you can not write the text-based xpath for this.

However, you can try with the below XPath:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc')]//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@class,'Iconstyle')]
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

and if it is unique:

You can click it like this:

```
export_btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class,'Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc')]//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@class,'Iconstyle')]")
export_btn.click()
```

or with **WebDriverWait:**

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class,'Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc')]//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@class,'Iconstyle')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: thank you cruisepandey. I should have provided more information regarding this question. Please look my update.

Comment: @hooch: I understand that the button `consists of 2 divided parts.` which part do you click manually to trigger the click?

Comment: hi cruisepandey, either one will pop up another button to click. when i click the area of the button, it will show so as upper arrow and Export word itself.  i update my question  with the image.

Comment: @hooch: What is the error that you got when you used this xpath `//div[starts-with(@class,'Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc')]//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@class,'Iconstyle')]`, See above I have attached an image, and xpath should work since it is unique in nature.

Comment: @ cruisepandey thank you for checking !  this is error that i get selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[starts-with(@class,'Buttonstyle__StyledIconContainer-sc')]//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@class,'Iconstyle')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)

Comment: I probalby have not provided enough information still.. I found the export button appears not always and found some script saying shadow-root. I attach the image on my question. banking site getting hard to do web scraping.... thank you cruisepandery !!

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as ***Export*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#export-button[aria-label='export transactions'][data-component-id='Button'][color='primary'] > div")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='export-button' and @aria-label='export transactions'][@data-component-id='Button']/div[contains(., 'Export')]")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the **clickable** element and to invoke [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on it you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#export-button[aria-label='export transactions'][data-component-id='Button'][color='primary'] > div"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='export-button' and @aria-label='export transactions'][@data-component-id='Button']/div[contains(., 'Export')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thank you undetected selnium! I have tried out but didn't work due to my bad. I should have provided more information regarding this question. please look at my update. I am bit messy to ask a question on stack overflow. please forgive me.

Comment: Considering the update to your question [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71188019/7429447) would remain unchanged as the facts you have updated are already factored in.

Comment: hi undetected Slenium, thank you so much for checking !      
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='export-button' and @aria-label='export transactions'][@data-component-id='Button']/div[contains(., 'Export')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\hooch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#export-button[aria-label='export transactions'][data-component-id='Button'][color='primary'] > div"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\hooch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I have noticed the export button appears only when they have transactions. I have attached the image of the code on my Question. If there are more information needed to solve, please let me know.