# Selenium clicking video to start

Tags: python, selenium

Currently a beginner, I am trying to click a video so it would start playing:

```
<div class="jw-media jw-reset"><video class="jw-video jw-reset" tabindex="-1" disableremoteplayback="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" x-webkit-airplay="deny" preload="metadata" src="/get_file/1/d9ce3f3e42f691a717900763bb60674bd97739d341/64000/64857/64857_hq.mp4/?d=3166&amp;br=626&amp;ti=1645665256" __idm_id__="147457" style="object-fit: fill;"></video></div>
```

I tried to use:

```
element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jw-media")
element.click()
```

as a css selector from right clicking the div from inspect elements and copying the css selector. I've also tried

```
element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jw-video jw-reset")
```

but that doesn't work either, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be an element with a label similar to play-button. have you found that? You might get better help if you provide more data (the site you are connecting to, or your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that the answer to the question was because the site I was trying to access had an ad on top of the video player which opened a new tab once it clicked on the video but I couldn't tell because I use an adblocker. I installed an adblocker by downloading the .xpi file and installing it with selenium.

```
browser.install_addon(filelocation, temporary=True)
```

Thanks for the replies and help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.jw-media.jw-reset > video.jw-video.jw-reset[src]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='jw-media jw-reset']/video[@class='jw-video jw-reset' and @src]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```