# Python selenium Error "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've tried for several hours to click a button on webpage with codes below but can't find solution.

I tried to click it with Xpath, full-Xpath, class, but it didn't work.
I heard that 'iframe' can occur error, but I don't see any tags named 'frame'
(Or can the iframe tag be in the document under a different name??)

For your information, when I press the button, it does not direct to a new page, but a pop-up window appears to fill out the contents.

**Error mesaage**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
```

**button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"> 반출기본정보 수정</button>
```

**Python code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

# Login

# put id
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://po-management.net/release/list")
time.sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem.send_keys(usernameStr)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(2)

# put password
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input73"]')
try:
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB).send_keys(passwordStr).perform()
    password.send_keys(passwordStr)
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# redirect
time.sleep(3)
url = "https://po-management.net/release/list"
driver.get(url)

# search
time.sleep(1)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("releaseSeqArray")
search.send_keys(vrorder)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# click1
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_link_text(vrorder).click()

# click2
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("btnReleaseVendorInfoModal").click()
```

Comment: Can you provide few more details, like HTML screenshot and few more lines of code

Comment: The element may not have been rendered yet and therefore is not available for Selenium to process. You may need to add a time.sleep(x) to allow time for the page to render the element before you try to click it.

Comment: I added full code and HTML

Comment: As per the attribute values, it might be a dialog window - kind of a pop-up. Check whether you have to switch to that window and try to do access that button.

Comment: Update the question with the Manual Steps to repro the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-warning.btn-sm#btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' and @id='btnReleaseVendorInfoModal']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and the *innerText*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space(text())='반출기본정보 수정']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't work. I got "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: " error

Comment: Yes. But I couldn't find solution in reference..