# How to click on ng-click angularJS element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'd like to click on a button shown on a webpage
It uses angularJS, and it seems I'm unable to click the right way, it's using ng-click

The page is that one:
https://structuredproducts.lukb.ch/products/find-products?search=group%255B%255D%3DBarrierReverseConvertible%26inListing%3D0

The button is the "Show all" one. If you want to land in the html, just right click on the button and right click inspect.

```
<a class="button button-primary inverted show-all ng-binding ng-scope" href="" title="Show all" ng-bind-html="'display_all' | translate" ng-if="media === 'regular' &amp;&amp; group.count > instrumentCountToShowPaging &amp;&amp; !group.pagingEnabled &amp;&amp; ($index === 0 || group.allowRender === true)" ng-click="showAll(group)">Show all</a>
```

I tried the followings, without much success:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

urlstart = 'https://structuredproducts.lukb.ch/products/find-products?search=group%255B%255D%3DBarrierReverseConvertible%26inListing%3D0'

chrome_options = Options()
prefs={'disk-cache-size': 4096 }
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
    
browser.get(urlstart)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="product-list"]/tabs/tab[4]/div/div/section/tabs/tab[2]/section/a[@ng-click=\"showAll(group)\"]""")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="product-list"]/tabs/tab[4]/div/div/section/tabs/tab[2]/section/a[@class='button button-primary inverted show-all ng-binding ng-scope' and starts-with(@ng-click,'showAll') and contains(.,'Show')]""").click()

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#product-list > tabs > tab:nth-child(5) > div > div > section > tabs > tab:nth-child(3) > section > a').click()
```

buttons[0].send_keys('((JavascriptExecutor)browser).executeScript("showAll(group);")')

```
WebDriverWait(browser , 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="product-list"]/tabs/tab[4]/div/div/section/tabs/tab[2]/section/a[text()='Show all']/../.."""))).click()
```

Any help / hint much appreciated

Comment: Please share all your code, not just a single line you couldn't do

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on <kbd>Show all</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Show all"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.button.button-primary.inverted.show-all.ng-binding.ng-scope[title='Show all'][ng-click^='showAll']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button button-primary inverted show-all ng-binding ng-scope' and @title='Show all'][ text()='Show all']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you I added the rest of the code
Also, I tried the 3 solutions, all of them resulted in the following error:
*** selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: If we take your xpath code, actually the element is found, but clicking on it produces the above error

Comment: So the xpath is perfect. Now you need to dig out if the element is within an iframe/shadow-root. See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447)

Comment: I don't understand - maybe that's because I'm not proficient with Selenium - but if I can find the element, then it should not be an issue about the frame , no ? Am I missing something ?