# How to click on the Login button using R Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, rselenium

I'm trying to login in on this site and I am succesful on  entering my login information, using the code below (without my own info ofcourse). However, I have not been successful in pressing the login bottum. Doing it manually, pressing the enter key also works.

I have included some of the code i have tried with out succes in the bottum.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.virtualmanager.com/da/login")
username <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value='//*[(@id = "email")]')
username$sendKeysToElement(list("myemail@thisisafakeemail.com"))
password <- remDr$findElement(using = "id",value="password")
password$sendKeysToElement(list("mypassword"))

#remDr$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = "enter"))
#login <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value="//input")
#login$sendKeysToElement(list("laptops",key="enter"))
#login$clickElement()
#remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value="//input")$clickElement()
#remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = login)
#login$click()
```

Comment: try this `xpath` `//*[@id="content"]/div/div/form/p[4]/input`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Can i ask how to derived that?

Comment: By using inspect from chrome (right click on the login button)

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element <kbd>Login</kbd> you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  login <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector",value="input[name='loginbtn'][value='Login']")
  login$clickElement()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  login <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value="//input[@name='loginbtn' and @value='Login']")
  login$clickElement()
  ```

---

### Reference

[Package ‘RSelenium’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf)