# selenium.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="button-submit"]"}

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this annoying error with selenium:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="button-submit"]"}
```

My code:

https://pastebin.com/BS49JibR

Button i'm trying to click with selenium:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl5m1.png

Comment: Is this ALL your code? Where is driver initialization and opening the page?

Comment: No, that's not all my code. StackOverflow didnt let me put it all

Comment: Really? Why you could put the code you showing here but some other code lines not?

Comment: Idk, said I had too much code so i removed parts of it

Comment: Can you post the url or is it private?

Comment: Sure !
https://pastebin.com/BS49JibR

Answer (score 1):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#button-submit[name='submit'][value='valider']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='button-submit' and @name='submit'][@value='valider']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: That didnt work, here's the error

\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BGMine13\Desktop\discordBotScreen\Discord Screenshot Bot.py", line 48, in on_message
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='button-submit']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\BGMine13\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @BGMine13 Somehow did you find some time to go through the reference discussions?

Comment: Yes, my chrome version is 99.0.4844.51 and chromedriver version is ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51