# Selenium find and Click button based on other tags

Tags: python, selenium

The below html consist of 1 of many rows.
Below is a sample row I need to click on the href. The href link is dependent on DataScience td tag and the Finance td tag they are fixed tags they dont change. The tag that I am looping that changes is SomeCategory each category will have a different number instead of the 328 for this particular link.

```
<tr>
   <th class=\"align-middle\" scope=\"row\">
      <span class=\"badge bg-primary position-relative py-2\">SomeCategory
         <span class=\"position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-secondary\">P3
         </span>
      </span>
   </th>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">DataScience</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">Finance</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">
    <div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\">
      <span data-bs-placement=\"left\" data-bs-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"\" data-bs-original-title=\"Show Application\" aria-label=\"Show Application\">
        <a class=\"btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary\" href=\"/repo/applications/328\">
           <svg class=\"bi flex-shrink-0\" height=\"18\" role=\"img\" width=\"18\">
               <use href=\"#icon_eye\"></use>
           </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

My objective is to find the href link by changing "SomeCategory" value so that I may go to that page. The other 2 values stay the same. By changing "SomeCategory" value the number would change creating a new link. How would I find this href based on the category change while other filter tags remain the same so i can return the href value and create the link for that category like the one below and use driver to go to that page

https://mybooks.topics.com/repo/applications/328

(This link wont work its only for sample purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the parent `tr` element based on the `SomeCategory` value and then find the `a` element containing the `href` inside it.
Something like this:

```py
//tr[.//span[contains(.,'SomeCategory')]]//a
```

**UPD**
Let's say you have `categories`, a list of values you want to use with `SomeCategory`.
You can format the XPath expression string with `SomeCategory` variable values as following:

```py
xpath_template = '//tr[.//span[contains(.,"{0}")]]//a'
for category in categories:
    xpath = xpath_template.format(category)
```

Now you can use the `xpath` above getting the correspondingly `href` links / elements.

Comment: Prophet Thank you! Your code works. The issues is that in order for it to work I must be on the page with the row or category I am looking for. Is there a way I can return the href link so I can create the link and go directly yo the page? My current string has all pages in one variable but for the driver to work the category must be on the active page.

Comment: Due to the above fact I reworded the question to return the href text value instead of click.

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer. I hope now it answers all your needs here.

Comment: Thank you! I had to modify your answer apparently. The single quotes fail I swapped it out for double quotes and  it does not fail.  but running the script does not return the href value. I see your building string in a loop cool. But not getting a href link to concatenate to page root.

Comment: In case your wondering about the single quote error 

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (2/ipykernel_11140/3559281934.py, line 1)
  File "C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2/ipykernel_11140/3559281934.py", line 1
    '//tr[.//span[contains(.,'{0}')]]//a'
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm not building the `href` itself here. You asked for locator to find the `a` element containing the `href` you wish to click. Right?

Comment: Thanks for correcting the quotes. I'm coding Java, here we define strings with double quotes and internal substring with single quotes. In Python the opposite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242784/discussion-between-leo-torres-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the desired element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- With respect to the element with text *DataScience*:

  ```
  text = "DataScience"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//td[text()='{text}']//following-sibling::td[2]//a[@class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary']"))).click()
  ```
- With respect to the element with text *Finance*:

  ```
  text = "Finance"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//td[text()='{text}']//following::td[1]//a[@class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: (undetected Selenium) not sure how this filter works because your doing them as individuals I would need to apply both filters together and with the revised end just return the href link. Thank you for your efforts. Great for future syntax reference.