# Find correct xpath with selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I'm currently working on a project with Selenium and webdriver. So far so good I can navigate through the website using selenium without any problem however, I would need to click on a specific icon to slides through to a date and time table. Issue is when looking at the HTML I have no idea what to locate with Selenium in order to click on that icon.

HTML sample:

```
<a _ngcontent-oyt-c155="" class="btn btn-soft-primary day-selector-navbutton"><i _ngcontent-oyt-c155="" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Usually I'm locating items by name, ID or Class but in that case I don't know where to got with.

Should I look for the xpath instead ?

Comment: In my experience css selectors are the best way to get desired element/elements. You can find them bu right clicking on the element in the inspection tool and selecting copy css selector

Comment: @Charalamm XPath and css selectors having almost the same capabilities to locate elements on the DOM while XPath do has some advantages like locating parent node based on the child node and locating element based on it text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to what you have shared here this XPath should work:

```py
'//a[@class="btn btn-soft-primary day-selector-navbutton"]//i[@class="fa fa-chevron-right"]'
```

I can't be completely sure if this locator is unique or if there is no iframe there etc.
You will possibly need to add some kind of wait here too. If so you should preferably use Expected Conditions explicit waits.

Comment: Did this worked?

Comment: Yes it is locating the arrow icon. Unfortunally there is a go back icon aswell, that the code above is refering to. HTML OF icon-left: <a _ngcontent-oyt-c155="" class="btn btn-soft-primary day-selector-navbutton"><i _ngcontent-oyt-c155="" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>

Comment: So it should be more specific for the class fa fa-chevron-right

Comment: Can you please share the link to that page or entire page HTML so we will be able to create unique locator? But please not in a comment, inside your question.

Comment: Ah, you mean with the internal `i` element it makes the locator unique?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for your time tho! @undeteced Selenium has given a working example :)

Comment: Your code works aswell! thank you sir

Comment: @Prophet To be more canonical you still can replace `//` with `/` as the `<i>` is the only descendant of `<a>`

Comment: I know, sure. But `//` is more flexible

Comment: No, it isn't. It isn't about being flexible but 2 different approaches for two distinct conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-soft-primary.day-selector-navbutton > i.fa.fa-chevron-right"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-soft-primary day-selector-navbutton']/i[@class='fa fa-chevron-right']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```