# How to click on an element by title with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to check a checkbox with selenium and the only available info is the title.
Is a dynamic element, so I need to select by the title.

I tried all the methods without success (contains @title, etc).

Can someone please help? I'm beginning to code.

The xpath is:

```
/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/span[1]/input
```

The CSS Selector is:

```
#selectCommon > span:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" title="AM - AMERICAS">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element with title as ***AM - AMERICAS*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[title^='AM'][title$='AMERICAS']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@title, 'AM') and contains(@title, 'AMERICAS')]").click()
  ```

Ideally to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[title^='AM'][title$='AMERICAS']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@title, 'AM') and contains(@title, 'AMERICAS')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: That worked! I was able to complete the task. Thanks a lot!