# Python - Selenium - Checkbox by contains value

Tags: python, selenium

So that is what the html looks like, and i want to check the box that contains "4845" in the ID or  in the Value, how can i do it ?

```
<tr id="tr_N031394845">
    <td>
<a href="i.do?data=whatever" onclick="forcePutInHistory=true; ajaxrequest(this.getAttribute('href'),this,true); return false; activecell(this);" title="04845 - B.pippo"> 04845 - B.pippo </a>
</td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" name="selectatm1" type="checkbox" value="N031394845|H" tabindex="5"></td>
<td class="                     icon mar_blabla_a
            "><span>4</span></td>
<td>HALA</td>
<td>03139</td>
<td>4845</td>
    <td class="tdsizemax">Stree 123</td>
<td class="icon crl0" title="Ok"><span>0</span></td>
<td class="icon crl0" title=" Ok"><span>0</span></td>
<td class="icon crl0" title="Ok"><span>0</span></td>


                <td class="tdimporto">4567.77</td>
        <td class="tdimporto">4567.77</td>
<td>31/03/2022 15:50</td>
<td>G20</td>
        <td>31</td>
    <td>04/04/2022 11:13</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
checkbox_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@value, '4845') or contains(@id, '4845')]")
if not checkbox_elem.is_selected():
    checkbox_elem.click()
```

Comment: This works but there is one problem, let's say i'm looking for "0440", then what happens is that 2 checkboxes gets selected which are:
value="N070624402|H"
and
value="N070840440|H"
What i need is only the second because it must look only for the last 4 digits

Comment: Does the value always end with "|H"? In that case you can use "0440|H" when searching for the matching checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the checkbox that contains ***4845*** in the *Value* you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[id^='tr'][id$='4845'] td > input[value*='4845']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[starts-with(@id, 'tr') and contains(@id, '4845')]//td/input[contains(@value, '4845')]").click()
  ```