# Using 'Alert' Interface in Selenium Java for alert conformation not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, alert

I used below selenium codes to click "OK" alert box, But It is not identifying, I dont knw wht's the reason, Can anyone help to solve this Issue ?

Element image:

[image]

Code trials:

```
 Alert click_on_update_button_Htwelveyes = driver.switchTo().alert();
    click_on_update_button_Htwelveyes.accept();
}
```

Console Output:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alert

An alert box is used if the user wants to make sure information comes through to the user. The user will have to click on <kbd>OK</kbd> to agree or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to deny the information.

[image: Alert_Ok_Cancel]

---

### This usecase

The following element doesn't seems to be an alert but a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) :

[image: HLR]

In such cases you need to locate the element with the Modal Dialog Box to locate the element with text as <kbd>Yes</kbd> or <kbd>No</kbd> and invoke [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the respective element of youe choice.

Comment: Hi undetected Selenium,  Thanks for ur answer.