# How to close the Flipkart login window by Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

When I run the below script the website is opened but the popup window is also opened. How do I close this popup window so the script can continue?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C://browserdrivers//chromedriver.exe")  
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button").click()
```

Screenshot:

[image: Take a look on screenshot also.]

Comment: We appreciate your responses, everyone :)
This was quite helpful for my Selenium homework.
I was able to use your code @undetected Selenium

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit trickee since all attributes of that X button element and it parent elements seems to be dynamic. Also that X text is not `x` or `X` letter.
So, I located it saying: "give me a button element containing some text but not containing 'OTP' text". This give an unique locator and the folllowing code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.flipkart.com/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()][not(contains(.,'OTP'))]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution would be issuing a random positioned click to dismiss the login window. For an example

```
driver.execute_script('el = document.elementFromPoint(47, 457); el.click();')
```

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>✕</kbd> opens in a *Modal Window*

---

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the desired element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='✕']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```