# When writing end to end selenium tests, should I navigate to a page or just open the URL?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

Say I need to submit a form on the 'Classes' page. I am testing the 'enroll into class' feature. Do I navigate to the page by clicking on the menu bar, or do I just directly open the URL of the page?

Comment: are you trying to test the function on the page, the menu, or the whole workflow from the point somebody logs into the application?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scenario you need to test.
As an autoimation engineer you need to work according to the documentation.
If no scenario defined you can choose easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Incase *clicking on the menu bar* is the part of your `@Test`, you have to access the base page and navigate to the desired page by invoking [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the menu bar.

Else you can directly open the URL of the page.