# Python Image/Button click via selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need help to click a specific Image on a Website.
Its in an iFrame too.

The HTML:

```
<i class="icon-willi-vote fxf-do-multivote" data-mv-id="1622095851001a" data-mission-id="97d05b44d86fb83b">
```

Snapshot of HTML:

[image: HTML Code]

Snapshot of the iframe:
[image: iFrame]

How can I use this button/image with selenium and can I do it with

```
driver.find_element(...)
```

I tried find_element by xpath, class and id, but i cant find the way to get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<i class="icon-willi-vote fxf-do-multivote" data-mv-id="1622095851001a" data-mission-id="97d05b44d86fb83b">
```

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.icon-willi-vote.fxf-do-multivote[data-mv-id][data-mission-id]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon-willi-vote fxf-do-multivote'][@data-mv-id and @data-mission-id]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.icon-willi-vote.fxf-do-multivote[data-mv-id][data-mission-id]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon-willi-vote fxf-do-multivote'][@data-mv-id and @data-mission-id]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

The desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) and if the values within the attributes `data-mv-id="1622095851001a"` and `data-mission-id="97d05b44d86fb83b"` remains constant throughout you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.willi.aka.krone.at']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.icon-willi-vote.fxf-do-multivote[data-mv-id='1622095851001a'][data-mission-id='97d05b44d86fb83b']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://www.willi.aka.krone.at')]")))    
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon-willi-vote fxf-do-multivote'][@data-mv-id='1622095851001a' and @data-mission-id='97d05b44d86fb83b']"))).click()
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thx, but there are several ".icon-willi-vote.fxf-do-multivote" Buttons on the Homepage, i need a way to include the specific Button/Icon with: data-mv-id="1622095851001a" data-mission-id="97d05b44d86fb83b"
Especially the Numbers, so the Program does not click the wrong Button.
Thats the only way to get the specific Button.

I can send u the whole Website, if u want

Comment: @DanielR The values within _`data-mv-id="1622095851001a"`_ and  _`data-mission-id="97d05b44d86fb83b"`_ are dynamically generated. So we need to uniquely identify them relating to it's ancestors. Update the question with then text based HTML including the ancestor elements.

Comment: As i know, these 2 Data Values stayed the same all day long an in every Browser i tested, there is no other way to uniquely identify the button in the backend.
here is the website: https://www.krone.at/3024904

Comment: I think the problem is a iframe, the button/image is in an iframe. I uploaded a Image of the iFrame.

Comment: @DanielR Yes, you are correct, I presumed you already taken care of the iframe early in your code. Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks mate, it works now exactly like i want!! Really nice job, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the element with css selector and class names:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon-willi-vote.fxf-do-multivote")
```

If the element is found successfully you can then .click() on the element or perform other operations.

Comment: There are more .icon-willi-vote.fxf-do-multivote Buttons on the Homepage, i need a way to include the specific Button/Icon with: data-mv-id="1622095851001a" data-mission-id="97d05b44d86fb83b"